# rust - all() - return false on empty iter

Tags: rust

Is there a way to make `all()` method return false on empty iter ?

example

```rust
let list = "";
let res = list.chars().all(|c| c == 'a');
println!("{}", res); // res here will print true and I want it to be false
```

I'm open for any other solution.

Comment: !list.is_empty() && list.chars().all(|c| c == 'a')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to check on the string whether it is empty or not

```
let list = "";
let res = !list.is_empty() && list.chars().all(|c| c == 'a');
println!("{}", res); // res here will print false
```

Comment: OP asked explicitly for a solution on an empty iter[ator]. A generic `Iterator` does not have an `is_empty()`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `trait` to implement a new function `all_not_empty()` that returns true iff the predicate, i.e. the test function, matches all items of the iterator and the iterator is not empty. Then we implement this `trait` for all `Iterator`s:

```rust
pub trait AllNotEmpty<T>: Iterator<Item = T> {
    fn all_not_empty(&mut self, predicate: fn(T) -> bool) -> bool;
}

impl<T, I> AllNotEmpty<T> for I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    fn all_not_empty(&mut self, predicate: fn(T) -> bool) -> bool {
        match self.next() {
            Some(item) => predicate(item) && self.all(predicate),
            None => false,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let predicate = |c| c == 'a';
    let empty = "";
    let nonempty_false1 = "b";
    let nonempty_false2 = "aba";
    let nonempty_true = "aaa";
    assert!(!empty.chars().all_not_empty(predicate));
    assert!(!nonempty_false1.chars().all_not_empty(predicate));
    assert!(!nonempty_false2.chars().all_not_empty(predicate));
    assert!(nonempty_true.chars().all_not_empty(predicate));
}
```

The advantage of this is, that the trait can be used for any `Iterator` of any type and not only on objects that implement `is_empty()`.